# trying to use terraform output in same module to configure efs replica's tags/policy/etc

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

starting out small with creating the file system and replication and then using the "destination[0].file_system_id" output to then assign some tags. Once I have the format, I can then do it to assign file system policies, vpcs, subnets, security groups etc...

I cannot figure out how to use/reference the output of the replica file system id (destination id) in subsequent resource configs within the same module.

I am doing all of this in one tf script so I can use the base text as a template that I can replace the file name with the actual names I will create so I don't need variables in this case as the requirements will vary from request to request.

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
  encrypted = true
  tags = {
    Name        = "efs"
    Team        = "infra"
    Environment = "mod"
    Business    = "enterprise"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_replication_configuration" "efs" {
  source_file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  destination {
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs-dr" {
  id = aws_efs_replication_configuration.efs.destination[0].file_system_id
  depends_on = [aws_efs_replication_configuration.efs]
  provider = aws.oh
  tags = {
    Name        = "efs-dr"
    Team        = "infra"
    Environment = "mod"
    Business    = "enterprise"
  }
}

output "destination_file_system_id" {
  value = aws_efs_replication_configuration.efs.destination[0].file_system_id
}
```

terraform apply returns the following:

```
Error: Invalid or unknown key
│
│   with aws_efs_file_system.efs-dr,
│   on efstemplate.tf line 59, in resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs-dr":
│   59:   id = aws_efs_replication_configuration.efs.destination[0].file_system_id
```

Comment: I don't think you need the second EFS file system. The plan works (and output) if you remove it.

Comment: thanks Marko. so how do I tag a file system in the same module if I don't know its id?

Comment: Where did you find tagging of the remote file system can be done? I just glanced at this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-replication-for-amazon-elastic-file-system-efs/, and I don't see that option.

Comment: once the efs replication is created via the GUI, you can assign tags via the GUI for the replica along with policies, network, security groups, etc...). I am trying to do this in one single terraform module assigning the tags with the output "destination[0].file_system_id" as spelled out in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/efs_replication_configuration but I am just not calling on it properly.

Comment: From what I can see, that cannot be done in terraform the way you are trying to, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: thank you. I will keep looking.